# ipcRenderer not getting triggered

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron, ipc, ipcrenderer

I'm trying to use IPC to communicate between *my react component* and *main electron process*.
[In component](https://github.com/maifeeulasad/open-code-electron/blob/7a0c5ead19018eedac73c255faf3c783b99d01a5/src/components/TabWindow.js#L25) :

```
export default class A extends React.Component{
.....
  openFile = () => {
    console.log('test');
    ipcRenderer.send('file-command', 'open');
  };
.....
}
```

And in [main.dev.ts](https://github.com/maifeeulasad/open-code-electron/blob/7a0c5ead19018eedac73c255faf3c783b99d01a5/src/main.dev.ts#L103) :

```
  mainWindow.webContents.on('file-command', () => {
    console.log('file open request');
  });

  mainWindow.on('file-command', () => {
    console.log('file open request');
  });

  ipcRenderer.on('file-command', () => {
    console.log('file open request');
  });
```

Tried all separately. But none of these works.

How can I use IPC properly, in my react-electron application. I've used this boilerplate : https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ipcRenderer` is the module you should, and do, use in the renderer process (either scripts attached to HTML pages if there is no `contextIsolation`, or preload otherwise).

The module to use in the main process is called `ipcMain`.

```js
const {ipcMain} = require('electron');

ipcMain.on('file-command', () => {
  console.log('file open request');
});
```

You may also want to look into `invoke`/`handle` in `ipcRenderer` and `ipcMain`, respectively. They make working with IPC a lot more pleasant.

Comment: i got another one coming on your way, i guess : https://stackoverflow.com/q/65804057/10305444